# Android Custom ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, listview, custom-adapter

I've Googled the heck out of making custom arrays, but I have not been able to find a tutorial that explains what I'm looking to achieve. I've tried converting the tutorials that comprise of adding a image and a textview, but somewhere during the conversion/replacement of the "image" for another textview the code goes to hell. I'm having a hard time trying to isolate the problem, since I do not know if changing one thing will affect other dependencies that are needed for a custom adapter.

Anyhow, on to my question: **Would someone be willing to write a very, very, very, generic, straight-forward, and simple Custom ArrayAdapter that expects two string values, that can be used with a ListView?...or, attempt to debug my attempt and hopefully spot what my problem is.**

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

I've included the code that I know is required, but I've been striking out with everything else.

custom_listview.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
     tools:context=".LoginActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Please wait.."
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/txtFieldName" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Please wait.."
        android:id="@+id/txtFieldValue" />
</LinearLayout>
```

CustomListViewAdapter.java

```
public class CustomListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private final Context context;
    private final String[] fieldNames;
    private final String[] fieldValues;


    public CustomListViewAdapter(Context context, String[] fieldNames, String[] fieldValues) {
        super(context, R.layout.custom_listview, fieldNames, fieldValues);
        this.context = context;
        this.fieldNames = fieldNames;
        this.fieldValues= fieldValues;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_listview, parent, false);
        TextView txtField= (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtFieldName);
        TextView txtValue= (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtFieldValue);
        txtField.setText(fieldNames[position]);
        txtValue.setText(fieldValues[position]);

        return rowView;
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setListAdapter(new CustomListViewAdapter(this, "myTestField", "myTestValue"));

    }


}
```

Error message I'm receiving:

> Error:(20, 9) error: no suitable constructor found for
>   ArrayAdapter(Context,int,String[],String[]) constructor
>   ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,int,List) is not
>   applicable (actual argument String[] cannot be converted to int by
>   method invocation conversion) constructor
>   ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,List) is not applicable
>   (actual and formal argument lists differ in length) constructor
>   ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,int,String[]) is not applicable
>   (actual argument String[] cannot be converted to int by method
>   invocation conversion) constructor
>   ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,String[]) is not applicable
>   (actual and formal argument lists differ in length) constructor
>   ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,int) is not applicable (actual
>   and formal argument lists differ in length) constructor
>   ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int) is not applicable (actual and
>   formal argument lists differ in length)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you get is because you are calling `super(context, R.layout.custom_listview, fieldNames, fieldValues);` on your constructor while there is no such constructor that takes two `String[]` parameters available for the `ArrayAdapter` class.

You should look at the documentation for `ArrayAdapter` [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) and find a suitable constructor to be used in your subclass. For example:

```
public CustomListViewAdapter(Context context, String[] fieldNames, String[] fieldValues) {
        super(context, R.layout.custom_listview);
        ...
    }
```

EDIT:
[Here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#arrayAdapter) is a good tutorial on `ListView` and `ArrayAdapters`.

Comment: I had to play around with this for a while, but the constructor documentation helped me find out why my code built without errors, but did not display the listview content. So when you match up the fields for the given constructor, will the rest of the objects be included automatically?

 super(context, R.layout.custom_listview, fieldNames); <--did the trick, although I defined two String Arrays in the method (fieldNames and fieldValues)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to extend `BaseAdapter` instead of `ArrayAdapter`, here's a great article on good practices when writing adapters: http://www.piwai.info/android-adapter-good-practices/

It covers basically all you need when creating an adapter.

Comment: I glanced at the material and if an ArrayAdapter is an extension of a BaseAdapter, it sounds like I'd be reinventing the wheel. I'll go back and read the rest of the article to see if I'm missing out on something that makes the BaseAdapter superior to the ArrayAdapter. The amount of flexibility stands out so far. Thank you for the reference and suggestion.